# Round all numbers in CSV to two decimal points

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting, rounding

I want to round (or simply remove) all numbers in a CSV file after the second decimal place.

I'm aware of `[Math]::Round()` and .NET versions of `'{0:f2}'`. Just don't know how I would apply this to an entire CSV file.

Comment: import the CSV file to powershell, and process each item with the [system.math]::round you mentioned, then export to a new csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have csv file like this:

```
Name  Num1       Num2       Num3     
----  ----       ----       ----     
Test1 4.2414     346.2425   33.24124 
Test2 123.35235  56.35235   326.23535
Test3 12424.2424 57.3525    466.3525 
Test4 4364.343   12.241212  1.12424  
Test5 12.552353  464.352353 346.4646 
Test6 323.535235 46.235235  235.2352
```

Import the CSV file and run this:

```
$csv = import-csv C:\temp\testfile.csv
foreach ($Item in $csv)
{
$Item.Num1 = [math]::Round($Item.Num1,2)
$Item.Num2 = [math]::Round($Item.Num2,2)
$Item.Num3 = [math]::Round($Item.Num3,2)
}

## To save to new file
$Csv | Export-Csv C:\temp\testfile2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Your output will be:

```
Name  Num1     Num2   Num3  
----  ----     ----   ----  
Test1 4.24     346.24 33.24 
Test2 123.35   56.35  326.24
Test3 12424.24 57.35  466.35
Test4 4364.34  12.24  1.12  
Test5 12.55    464.35 346.46
Test6 323.54   46.24  235.24
```

Comment: Not the golden ticket I was looking for but just as good. Thanks!